# Bring Changes from Main branch to feature branch after failed merge/revert

Tags: git, github, merge, rebase, revert

I merged the Main branch into my feature branch, but in doing so, I ended up deleting a portion of the files that ran the feature. I reverted the changes so the feature was not lost. Now, I believe rebasing is what I wanted to do initially, though when I attempt to rebase the feature branch with the updated main branch, I am notified there are no commits to be rebased, even though some of the files in main are more up to date with the changes I want, than the feature branch. I need to bring the updated files in main over to my feature branch but I am unsure what I should do. I am working with Git.

Answer (score 0):

You will perhaps have a simpler time using `git cherry-pick <range of commits>` :

- in the history of your repository :

  ```
  git log --oneline --graph main feature
  # or use a graphical viewer
  ```

  spot the hash of the commit where `feature` forked from `main` (let's call this commit `fork`)
- from your `main` branch, run :

  ```
  git cherry-pick fork..feature
  ```